# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: php, jquery, json

Estou consumindo dados retornados de um **Web Service JSON**, na qual eu percorro **colunas de arrays**, para **comparar** valores entre as URLs e **se iguais**, substituir por seu respectivo nome. Temos nomes de *equipes, locais, categorias e modalidades*, cada qual com seu código de identificação, ex:

Retorno de um dos resultados da **URL EQUIPES** usando o var_dump:

```
array(1241) { 
 [0]=> array(5) { 
  ["codigo"]=> string(1) "4"
  ["modalidade"]=> string(1) "2" 
  ["categoria"]=> string(1) "4" 
  ["nome"]=> string(8) "Arbos SA" 
  ["abreviado"]=> string(3) "ARB" 
}
```

A **string "codigo"** da *URL Equipes* é **comparada** com a **string "codigo"** da *URL resultados*, e se as duas forem iguais, subistitui o retorno pelo nome da equipe, e a mesma regra se aplica as outras URLs.
Criei um script usando **PHP** para filtra-los e **jQuery** para printar as tabelas, o script funciona, mas as vezes me retornava alguns erros como:

> Illegal string offset
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Fui estudando aqui no forum e na documentação do php e encontrei soluções como o **is_array, isset e empty,** tentei aplica-las da forma correta, mas como seu leigo em php creio que não está correto, e ainda por cima depois de mexer tanto no código, começou a retornar:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

no console do chrome, ao que eu pesquisei, alguma das chaves está fechada de forma errada, eu já procurei o erro e não encontrei onde...
peço desesperadamente por ajuda, alguém que possa me explicar as aplicações e syntaxe para que eu possa rodar o código sem erros, agradeço desde já seu tempo e atenção!

Ex URL:

```
$api_resultados = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/resultados?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&inicio=2018-'. $dm .'-01&fim='. $dt .'-12-31';
$resultados = wp_remote_get( $api_resultados );
$resultado = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $resultados), true);
```

Os erros se dão entre essas linhas, as vezes nos array_column com os array_search, as vezes no foreach:

```
<?php
        if(!empty($campeonato) && !is_array($campeonato) && !is_array($resultado) && !is_array($equipe) && !is_array($local) && !is_array($categoria) && !is_array($modalidade)){

        print_r('Não encontrado');

    }else{

    $col =  array_column($equipe, 'codigo');

    $loc =  array_column($local, 'codigo');

    $cat =  array_column($categoria, 'codigo');

    $mod =  array_column($modalidade, 'codigo');

    foreach($campeonato as $camp){

            if(!is_array($camp)){

            }else{

                foreach($resultado as $result){

                    if(!is_array($result)){

                }else{

                    if(isset($result['mandante']) && isset($result['visitante']) && isset($result['local']) && isset($result['data'])) {

                $key4 = array_search($camp['categoria'], $cat);

                $categorizacao = '';

                if($key4){
                    $categorizacao = $categoria[$key4]['nome'];
                }


                $key5 = array_search($camp['modalidade'], $mod);

                $modalidadez = '';

                if($key5){
                    $modalidadez = $modalidade[$key5]['nome'];
                }

                $key1 = array_search($result['mandante'], $col);

                $mandante = '';

                if($key1){
                    $mandante = $equipe[$key1]['nome'];
                }


                $key2 = array_search($result['visitante'], $col);

                $visitante = '';

                if($key2){
                    $visitante = $equipe[$key2]['nome'];
                }


                $key3 = array_search($result['local'], $loc);

                $localizacao = '';

                if($key3){
                    $localizacao = $local[$key3]['nome'];
                }


                $data = $result['data'];
                $data = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data));

                $i = 0;

                if(isset($camp['codigo']) && isset($result['campeonato']) && $camp['codigo'] == $result['campeonato']){
                    $retorno_resultados[++$i][] = array(
                        'mandante' => $result['mandante'], 
                        'visitante' => $result['visitante'],
                        'nm_mandante' => $mandante,
                        'nm_visitante' => $visitante,
                        'nm_cat' => $categorizacao,
                        'nm_mod' => $modalidadez,
                        'nm_local' => $localizacao,
                        'id' => $camp['codigo'],
                        'modalidade' => $camp['modalidade'],
                        'categoria' => $camp['categoria'],
                        'data' => $result['data'],
                        'data_certa' => $data,
                        'placar1n' => $result['placar1n'],
                        'placar2n' => $result['placar2n'],
                        'placar1p' => $result['placar1p'],
                        'placar2p' => $result['placar2p'],
                        'placar1s' => $result['placar1s'],
                        'placar2s' => $result['placar2s'],
                        'jogo' => $result['jogo'],
                        'horario' => $result['horario'],
                        'jogo' => $result['codigo'],
                    );
                };
                };
            };
        };
    };
    };
    };

<script>

     $(function() {

        <?php foreach($retorno_resultados as $val){ ?>

        var html3 = '';
        var id='';

        <?php foreach($val as $res){ ?>


        html3 += '<tr><td><?php echo $res['data_certa'];?>&nbsp às &nbsp<?php echo $res['horario'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['nm_local'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['nm_mandante'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['nm_visitante'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['nm_mod']?>&nbsp<?php echo $res['nm_cat']?></td></tr>';

        id = <?php echo $res['id'] ?>;

        <?php } ?>
        $('#equipesTbody').html(html3);

        <?php } ?>

    });
```

Estou online o tempo todo se precisarem de mais informações, ou caso queiram conversar no chat, também posso passar as URLs para comparar os valores para a explicação, um forte abraço!

Comment: O primeiro erro que você mencionou "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach" acontece porque na primeira linha do código é feito a vericação !empty($campeonato) ou seja se esse valor for vazio ele vai cair no else que é onde ocorre o foreach, entao acredito que deva ser tirado a negação ! e deixar só empty($campeonato)

Comment: O segundo erro geralmente acontece quando é aberto uma tag php errada. O código php que você mandou está correto, isso se foi aberto <?php no começo (esta omitido no stackoverflow então não sei).

Comment: removi a negação e até agora não deu erro, a tag está aberta sim, desculpe esqueci de incluí-la, como está retornando o erro Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, está interferindo em um shortcode abaixo, se eu removo o script, o shortcode volta ao normal.

Comment: o carregamento da página também demora um pouco com o script incluído, por acaso eu escrevi de forma muito ruim?

Comment: O código tem bastante coisa que podia ser melhorado (estética), em performace não deveria estar demorando afinal é coisa simples que tu ta fazendo, oque deve demorar é a resposta que tu faz pra api.

Comment: Quando ao segundo problema do erro "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" você ta fechando a tag php no final do arquivo? por tar incluindo ele em outro arquivo pode dar problema se não estiver fechado. O problema não deve ser no php e sim no lugar de onde você ta usando ele.

Comment: eu encontrei o erro, de syntax, muito obrigado, as suas dicar ajudaram muito, creio que a esta demorando devido ao jeito que eu escrevi o jquery, irei adiciona-lo no post, eu gostaria de remover as tags do php com o foreach e usar a função each do jquery, poderia me explicar como proceder?

Comment: adicionei no final do php, como está no meu código, mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Se tu quiser isola o tratamento só no php da pra ser feito +- [assim](https://pastebin.com/sjwbdp2c), no caso de realmente quiser fazer só com javascript tu vai ter que transforma o array que o php retornou pra uma forma que o javascript possa ler, acredito que só um json_encode no resultado do teu php já de certo, quem sabe [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript/5619038#5619038) te ajude. No final do foreach no php da um $retorno_resultados = json_encode($retorno_resultados);